# database is not refreshing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I connected a SQLite db to my ipad app. where the db has two tables, 1 table which populates the data and other tables save the data given in the app. but the problem is that my Database is not refreshing and saving the data.. for example: if i add new name to the table it doesn't populate automatically and it is populating only if i add the db file again with different name and also it is not saving the data which i want to save.

Kindly give me your valuable suggestions

please find my code for your reference:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PersonDatabase.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>{
    PersonDatabase *perDas;
    NSString * nameString;
    NSString * statusString;
      sqlite3 *database;
    NSString * empString;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *signIn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *signOut;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString * nameString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString * statusString;

-(IBAction)signin:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)signout:(id)sender;
@end


#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PersonInfo.h"
#import "PersonDatabase.h"


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize signIn;
@synthesize signOut;
@synthesize nameLabel;
@synthesize  nameString,statusString;;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (perDas == nil) {
        perDas = [[PersonDatabase alloc] init];
    }

    [tableView setDataSource:perDas];
    [tableView setDelegate:perDas];
    perDas.view = perDas.tableView;
}

-(IBAction)signin:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@",perDas.string1);
    nameString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:perDas.string1];
     statusString=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"IN"];
    {
        NSLog(@"passed");
        sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

        const char *dbpath = [perDas.databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"pass");
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO status (names, staus, signin, singnout) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", datetime(), \"%@\")", nameString, statusString,empString];
            NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            int results= sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
                NSLog(@"%i", results);
            if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
                NSLog(@"done");
            }else {
                printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);

    }
    }}
-(IBAction)signout:(id)sender{
 NSLog(@"%@",perDas.string1);}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTableView:nil];
    [self setSignIn:nil];
    [self setSignOut:nil];
    [self setNameLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PersonInfo : NSObject{
    int unique;
    NSString * nam;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign)int unique;
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString * nam;
-(id) initWithUniqueId:(int)uniqueId name:(NSString *)name;
@end



#import "PersonInfo.h"

@implementation PersonInfo
@synthesize unique,nam;

-(id) initWithUniqueId:(int)uniqueId name:(NSString *)name{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        self.unique=uniqueId;
        self.nam=name;

    }
    return self;
}

@end



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "PersonInfo.h"

@interface PersonDatabase : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString * databasePath;
    NSMutableArray *tableOne;
    NSString * string1;
    NSString * dateString;
    NSString * timeString;
     sqlite3 *database;
    NSString * empString;

}
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray  *tableOne;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSString * string1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSString *  databasePath;

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void)readDataFromDatabase;

@end


#import "PersonDatabase.h"
#import "PersonInfo.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation PersonDatabase
@synthesize tableOne, string1,databasePath;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    databaseName=@"log.sqlite3";

    NSArray *documentPaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"a");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [tableOne count]; }

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell= nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];}

    PersonInfo * temp =(PersonInfo *)[self.tableOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=temp.nam;

    return cell;
}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    string1 = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",string1);
}
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
    tableOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM names";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
                char *nameChars=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1);
                NSString *name=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
                PersonInfo *info=[[PersonInfo alloc]initWithUniqueId:uniqueId name:name];
                [tableOne addObject:info];
            }            
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
@end
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: No one is going to read your entire code, point out exactly where you  are facing issue, and have you tried debugging the issue?

Comment: It is not fair to just dump your code. You should tell us where you think it fails.

Comment: Mundi And Rishi: if i know whats the error, why i will post the question????? the code builds fine and i wrote my problem in my Question???!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are my DB functions and they are working fine try this..

```
-(void)dbconnect{

    self.dbName=@"MyDb.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.dbPath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.dbName];
    NSLog(@"DBPATH%@",self.dbPath);
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
}
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    //check file exists in document directory
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.dbPath];

    //if file exists in document directory then return

    if(success)
        return;

    //if file do not exists copy it in documents directory

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.dbPath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];

}
-(sqlite3_stmt*) PrepareStatement:(const char *)sql{
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;
    // Init the animals Array

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        const char *sqlStatement = sql;
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,-1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            //NSLog(@"COMPILED STATEMENT: %@",compiledStatement);
            return compiledStatement;

        }
    }
    return nil;
}
- (void) showException :(NSException *)e {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Trade Voice" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error - %@",e.name] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
/*DB CONN End*/
-(BOOL) sleepDatabase:(sqlite3 *)dbase {
    if (sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &dbase) == SQLITE_BUSY || sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &dbase) == SQLITE_LOCKED) {
        NSLog(@"Database in sleep");
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

//////code to save update delete

```
-(void)insertMaterialDetail:(Material *)objMaterial{
    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char* sql = "INSERT INTO Material (name,amt) VALUES (?,?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        statement = [self PrepareStatement:sql];

        int a1=sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [objMaterial.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        int a2 = sqlite3_bind_double(statement, 2, objMaterial.amt);

        //NSLog(@"query %s",sql);
        if (statement)
        {
            if (a1 != SQLITE_OK || a2 != SQLITE_OK )
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                return;
            }

            sqlite3_step(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
}
-(int)updateMaterial:(Material *)objMaterial{

    @try {

        if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &delDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

            sqlite3_stmt* statement = nil;
            const char* sql = "update Material set name = ?, amt = ? where material_id = ?";



            statement = [self PrepareStatement:sql]; 

            int a1 = sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [objMaterial.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            int a2 = sqlite3_bind_double(statement,2, objMaterial.amt);
            int a3 = sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, objMaterial.material_id);

            if (statement)
            {

                if (a1 != SQLITE_OK || a2 != SQLITE_OK || a3 != SQLITE_OK) 
                {
                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    return 0;
                }

                sqlite3_step(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        [self showException:e];
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(delDatabase);
        return 1;
    }


}

-(void)deleteMaterial:(int)Materialid{
    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([self.dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt;
        const char *sql = "Delete from Material where material_id = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
        sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, Materialid);

        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not passing throughout the methods